# Matplotlib + Tensorflow not displaying image

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, neural-network

I am making a neural network to recognise handwritten digits using TensorFlow.

I am using TensorFlow version 2.14.0

I imported:

```
import os
import cv2
import NumPy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
```

I made the model using:

```
#DATA
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)  =  mnist.load_data()

#Normalise
x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

#NEURAL_NETWORK
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

model.save('handwritten.model')
```

I am running the network using:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('handwritten.model')

image_number = 1
while os.path.isfile(f"Neural Network/TensorFlow/Datasets/Handwritten_Digits{image_number}.png"):
    # try:
    img = cv2.imread(f"Neural Network/TensorFlow/Datasets/Handwritten_Digits{image_number}.png")[:,:,0]
    img = np.invert(np.array([img]))
    prediction = model.predict(img)
    print(f"This digit is probably a {np.argmax(prediction)}")
    plt.imshow(img,[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
```

I ran the code and it gave me the error:

I TensorFlow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

When running, this is all I get when I use it on images provided by myself - is there anything that needs to be changed?

Comment: You do not need to do anything, training MNIST is not computationally intensive at all, the warning is just informative.

Comment: `import NumPy as np` ??  => `NumPy` = `numpy`